# What would this concept be called?

Tags: python, variables, concept

I am trying to do something in code, that is not working and I'm not even sure what to google for. 
The actual case is in python using tkinter, but here is a simple example that will make the point.

I want to create a bunch of variables so I made a list of tuples:

`vars = [('var1', 'value1'), ('var2', 'value2')]`

Then I want to use a syntax like this:

```
for item in vars:
    item[0] = item[1]
```

This will make `item[0]` equal to `'value1'`. what I want it to do is make `var1` equal to `'value1'`.

I hope its clear what I'm trying to do. And I have a feeling its even trivial once I can get a hint in the right direction.

This is in python but I think the concept is more universal.

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to dynamically set local variables named in your `vars` list? Generally, you don't do that. Stick to a dictionary for those names instead.

Comment: "Dynamically named variables" is probably the name you're looking for, but it's nearly always a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary for this purpose:

```
d = dict(vars)
```

Then you can access `var1` by doing `d['var1']`, which will give you `value1`.

Comment: If you have a list of pairs that you want to turn into a dict and you don't require any extra work to be done with the values, `d = dict(vars)` will do just that. Dict comprehensions are also nice if you'd like to apply a simple transformation, eg. `d = {key: 2 * value for key, value in vars}`

Comment: Awesome that works nicely. So I wanted dictionaries and not tuples. Thanks.